# Bundled product remove "Price as configured"

Tags: bundled-product

i want to remove product remove "Price as configured" for bundled products how can i do it

i make bundled products in such way that all items are set required and can not be skipped so no need of "Price as configured"

form where it can be removed please guid me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you will activate the "Template path hints" you will see that the template responsible for rendering this price is `template/bundle/catalog/product/view/price.phtml`. Now, if you go into `bundle.xml` you will find this template added like this with the name `bundle.prices`

```
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle translate="label" module="bundle">
            ......
            <reference name="product.info">
                <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>bundle</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block><template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template></action>
                <block type="bundle/catalog_product_price" name="bundle.prices" as="bundle_prices" template="bundle/catalog/product/view/price.phtml">
                    <action method="setMAPTemplate"><tmpl>catalog/product/price_msrp_item.phtml</tmpl></action>
                </block>
                 ......
            </reference>
            ......
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>
```

The cleanest way to removing this template is to create a new file under your `layout` folder, called `local.xml`, and add the following code into it. Basically, calling the `bundle.prices` name, under `remove` tag, the template will be removed from the bundle product page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle translate="label" module="bundle">
            <reference name="product.info">
                <remove name="bundle.prices" />
            </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the text "Price as configured" you can try to add a Custom Layout update against each individual bundle product from Admin > Catalog > Manage Products > Edit Product > Design > Custom Layout Update, as in the screen shot below:
[image]
With this option

1. you can remove the text "Price as configured" as well as keep the bundle product price functionality available in case if its needed in future.
2. It do not require a developer to make the changes in the code and is manageable from Admin

Code to be add in Custom Layout Update is a below:

```
 <PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle translate="label" module="bundle">
        <reference name="product.info">
            <remove name="bundle.prices" />
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>
```